# Best way to construct XML from JSON in Golang

Tags: xml, json, go

I have a middleware where I receive JSON input and with user credentials and needs to grab them to construct a full XML with various other data.

Suppose I have below code to decode JSON:

```
json.NewDecoder(r.Request.Body).Decode(entityPointer)
```

What is the most efficient way to construct XML from here?

I thought I could just match with struct and use them or parse them with existing XML template and replace the template variables?

if I had for example `{username: '11', password: 'pass'}` as request, How can I construct below XML out of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same struct for both XML and JSON, for example:

```
type Person struct {
    Id        int    `xml:"id,attr"`
    FirstName string `xml:"name>first" json:"first"`
    LastName  string `xml:"name>last" json:"last"`
}

func main() {
    j := `{"id": 10, "first": "firstname", "last":"lastname"}`
    var p Person
    fmt.Println(json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &p), p)
    out, _ := xml.MarshalIndent(p, "\t", "\t")
    fmt.Println(string(out))

}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/zVW4Z-5cQY)

Check the xml examples @ http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#example_Encoder

//edit

Well, since you already have a template you could use [`html/template`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/), for [example](http://play.golang.org/p/ykbLvo6-sa):

```
const xmlTmpl = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE api SYSTEM "api.dtd">
<api version="6.0">
    <request>
<reqClient returnToken="N">
    <user>{{.AdminUsername}} </user>
    <password>{{.AdminPassword}}</password>
</reqClient><reqValidate returnBalance="Y">
    <userName>{{.Username}}</userName>
    <password>{{.Password}}</password>
    <channel>M</channel>
</reqValidate></request>
</api>
`

var tmpl = template.Must(template.New("foo").Parse(xmlTmpl))

type Entity struct {
    AdminUsername      string `json:"-"`
    AdminPassword      string `json:"-"`
    Username, Password string
}

func main() {
    e := Entity{Username: "User", Password: "Loser"}
    //json.NewDecoder(r.Request.Body).Decode(&e)
    e.AdminUsername = "admin" // fill admin user/pass after parsing the request
    e.AdminPassword = "admin-password"
    fmt.Println(tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, e))
}
```

Comment: I've just updated my question with desired XML structure. How can I build that out of JSON input above?

Comment: What is minus for in json?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper `json:"-"`? that's so json wouldn't try to decode it, unless the admin user/pass are a part of the request then by all means remove that.